# raster info as table in R

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, table, data-frame

I want to display the information of a raster layer as a table or data frame in R. In particular, I am most interested in the raster name and resolution.

I want the information which shows by just reading the raster layer or by:

```
r <- raster("mypath/B01.tif")
print(r)
```

How to return print(r) as a table or data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
r_df <- as.data.frame(capture.output(print(r)))
```

then to pretty it up

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
r_df <- tidyr::separate(r_df, 1, into = c('param', 'data'), sep = ' : ')
r_df <- dplyr::filter(r_df, !is.na(data))
```

There are baseR methods for the above steps but tbh, life's too short.

NB What you're asking here isn't actually spatial even though raster is involved - the generic problem is 'put some console output in an object and make it look nice'. For future reference this kind of question fits stackoverflow better.